# Manipulating the data value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I set the value of name to the property personOne in object? So that name will have the value of Alex.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: '',
    object: { "personOne": "Alex", "personTwo": "Jack"}
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you give us an actual, real-usage example? Seems fairly clear the real scenario isn't as hard-coded, or you'd just do `name: 'Alex'` and be done with it. Are you loading `object` via AJAX or something? If so, a `computed` property is probably reasonable.

Comment: BTW this is not valid javascript object - it should be key -> value - `personOne: 'Alex'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the [life-cycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) like created [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) or [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) for setting initial data, loading data from API, etc, like following:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: '',
    object: { "personOne": "Alex", "personTwo": "Jack"}
  },
  methods: {
    setName (name) {
      this.name = name
    }
  },
  mounted () {
     this.setName(this.object.personOne)
  },
})
```

Comment: This seems a bit overcomplicated when a simple `computed` property would suffice.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think OP just wants a `computed` property as in that case he can just access `this.object.personOne`.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking OP has something else going on that they're not explaining well.

Answer (score 1):

From within the Vue object you write

`this.name = 'Alex'` and outside you write  `app.name = 'Alex'`

app.someDataField will change the data property called someDataField